# USB Device Control in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb

I want to selectively block and unblock usb devices based on their serial number. We can write kernel extensions to achieve the same. But this seems complicated and risky. So I would like to know is there any easy way to achieve the same in cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Easy Way" most probably not; though there may be an alternative method to using a kext, it likely would not be the most sensible way of tackling the issue. You could block all usb devices quite easily, but this isn't what you're asking.

I'd advise you to write a kernel extension, which isn't as hard as you may think. If you've not written one before, I recommend you read [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/OS-X-iOS-Kernel-Programming/dp/1430235365), which is predominantly concerned with writing kernel extensions.

Answer (score 1):

No. You basically need to write a kext to do this.